failed to run python.exe in vs code
When I try to run python 'Run python file in terminal' in vs code,I get this error in Terminal:
> PS I:\python\Exam> & ??/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe ??/Exam/S1/t1.py
Program 'python.exe' failed to run: Access is deniedAt line:1 char:1
+ & ??/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.e ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~.
At line:1 char:1
+ & ??/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.e ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed

?? is installation directory and my code is very simple:

print('Hello World!')

I can run my code in 'Run current file in interactive window' without any error.
My environment specifications:
windows 11 x64
python 3.12.2
vs code 1.87.2
What is the reason for this problem?
I try to run my python code in windows cmd and everything is good.

Can you try the below steps to resolve the issue:

In vscode add the python executable file location in settings.json file.

{
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\python.exe",
}

If the above step not working just try the below steps:

Uninstall the python from your machine and make sure that is not exist in any other location.
Reboot the host
Freshly install the latest python version in C:/ drive.
Set the environment variable for newly installed python.
try the step 1.


Not worked! I installed/ran python and VS code on an interanet user. Can this cause problems?

Can you check the size of /AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe is zero byte?

if yes, reinstall the python and check the size of the exe file? if size is zero copy python3.exe file to the your dest path.
Check the user has right permission to access the appdata dir and python.exe?
If you have multiple version of python disable it by settings -> App execution aliases. In the windows you just turn  of the app installer of multiple python version.



Add the local python path(C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312) before WindowsApps path(C:\Users/Username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps) in setting environment variable.

